# Swift : Error when trying to assign value to a Class object >> execution was interrupted reason exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, generics

I'm new to swift and programming , I am trying to understand this code below but I keep getting this error ***>>> execution was interrupted reason exc_bad_instruction (code=exc_i386_invop subcode=0x0)*** from playground. I thought I could simply assign x with class Product() and fill in the values, but I don't understand what the error is saying. Can someone please explain to me? How can I use this Class Product ?

```
class Product
{
    var title: String
    var description: String
    var image: UIImage
    var rating: ProductRating

    init(titled: String, description: String, imageName: String)
    {
        self.title = titled
        self.description = description
        if let img = UIImage(named: imageName) {
            image = img
        } else {
            image = UIImage(named: "default")!
        }
        rating = .Unrated
    }
}

var x = Product(titled: "test", description: "test", imageName: "test.jpg")
```

Comment: At a guess, `UIImage(named: "default")` is possibly not finding the image. Then when you force unwrap it with "!", you cannot unwrap nil and so you get that crash.

Comment: Hi @Michael You're right something going on with image if I comment image out => others work just fine. However, I have default.jpg in the Both DemoAssets / and Images.xcassets but I still get the same error. Any recommendation ?

Comment: Change it to `UIImage(named: "default.jpg")`